# Select max(pk) instead of sequence.nextval

Tags: oracle, best-practices

I have a client/superior who keeps suggesting that I select max(primary_key)
when I insert a new row.

I gut says it's **VERY** wrong but I don't have exact reasons to support my suggestion.
The only thing so far I can think of is when two people are trying to insert into the same table and getting data mixed up.

What are the reasons one should not rely on selecting max(primary_key) + 1
to generate a pk value ?

Comment: If you have two concurrent transactions that insert in this table both calculate the same value and one will fail.But why does he suggest this. What does he want to achieve by doing it this way instead of using sequences?

Comment: He said because it looks too plain on the user interface if it shows 1,2,3 instead of 'ABC-0001' that it looks more like a code. Is it acceptable for a real world application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presentation of the data should not be the determining factor in how the data is stored - especially in the case of a primary key.  That would be like saying that all dates need to be stored in the database as strings so that a particular date format could be displayed.

To make the select max(pk) + 1 work in a system with more than one user is to programmatically force only one session to get the next PK value at a time - seriously compromising your concurrency. Either that or you will have to write code to intercept the PK failure and try again.

The data displayed can be formatted in the presentation layer in any way that makes sense.  You can do a to_char to add the leading zero's in the select if needed - another string in the record could be appended - whatever would make it look more like a "code".  In our environment we just use the generated sequence as the identifier - its more important that it is generated efficiently and is unique than how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use sequence instead of max(pk), the reason is serialization. Also sequence increases manageability. Let your client try 'select max(pk)' in multi user environment and scale up the number of concurrent users then he understands himself. For more please [Sequence vs max primary key value + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980960/sequence-vs-max-primary-key-value-1)